# Label animation left and right inside the panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am doing a simple animation using a label panel and timer, how do I animate the label to left and right inside the panel when the form is open?

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If Label2.Right < 0 Then
        Label2.Left = Panel1.ClientSize.Width
    Else
        Label2.Left -= 10
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label2.Parent = Panel1
    Label2.Location = New Point(Panel1.ClientSize.Width,
                          Panel1.ClientSize.Height / 2 - (Label2.Height / 2))
    Timer1.Start()

End Sub
```

Comment: And what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: nothing happen.

Comment: no animation happen when i run the code

Comment: Works just fine for me. Where is `Label2` declared? Is it added onto the form (or panel) or not?

Comment: *"how do I animate the label to left and right"*. Is that actually what you want, or do you really want to animate it to the left only and then wrap it back to the right when it goes off the left edge?

Comment: Note that currently, the label only travels from right to left (and repeats once it reaches the left border). Is that what you want?

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes, thats exactly what i want

Comment: @41686d6564 yes

Comment: i just want that if the label reach the left of the panel, the label will repeat just like the animation of this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3a628545-8c19-4366-9875-a67239c37c37/make-label-animated-slide-from-left-to-right?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: @Josh As I said before, with your (unaltered) code, the label moves from right to left and repeats ([proof](https://i.imgur.com/iwCaRW7.gif)). If you're not getting the same result, you need to [edit] the question and provide a [repro]. Until then, it's very unlikely that anyone would be able to help you.

Comment: have you tried to do  Label2.Refresh()  ?